# Does the method getUsername() of interface UserDetails indicate that there must be a attribute "username" in an entity impl the interface?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I'm studying springboot on a website. The website gives a example project for spring security, following is a part of the code:
User entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id 
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
private Long id;

@NotEmpty(message = "name no empty")
@Size(min=2, max=20)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 20) 
private String name;

@NotEmpty(message = "email no empty")
@Size(max=50)
@Email(message= "wrong email format" )
@Column(nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
private String email;

@NotEmpty(message = "username no empty")
@Size(min=3, max=20)
@Column(nullable = false, length = 20, unique = true)
private String username;

@NotEmpty(message = "password no empty")
@Size(max=100)
@Column(length = 100)
private String password;

@Column(length = 200)
private String avatar;


@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_authority", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private List<Authority> authorities;

protected User(){

}

public User(Long id, String name, String username, String email){
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.email = email;
    this.username = username;
}


public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username){
    this.username = username;
}
@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> simpleAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (GrantedAuthority authority : this.authorities){
        simpleAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getAuthority()));
    }
    return simpleAuthorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(List<Authority> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}


@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getAvatar() {
    return avatar;
}

public void setAvatar(String avatar) {
    this.avatar = avatar;
}


@Override
public String toString(){
    return String.format("User[id = %d, name = '%s', username = '%s', email = '%s']", id, name, username, email);
}
}
```

UserService implementation:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService, UserDetailsService {
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Transactional
@Override
public User saveOrUpdateUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public User registerUser(User user) {
    return userRepository.save(user);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public void removeUser(Long id) {
    userRepository.delete(id);
}

@Override
public User getUserById(Long id) {
    return userRepository.findOne(id);
}

@Override
public Page<User> listUsersByNameLike(String name, Pageable pageable) {
    name = "%" + name + "%";//匹配相似
    Page<User> users = userRepository.findByNameLike(name, pageable);
    return users;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    return userRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
}
```

Security Configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true) 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

private static final String KEY = "waylau.com";

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();   
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder); 
    return authenticationProvider;
}



@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/fonts/**", "/index").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll() 
            .antMatchers("/admins/**").hasRole("ADMIN") /
            .and()
            .formLogin()   
            .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login-error") 
            .and().rememberMe().key(KEY) 
            .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");  
    http.csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/h2-console/**"); 
    http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin(); 

}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}


}
```

What I focus is the attribute "username" of User.java. There is no problem when running codes above.
But after altered "username" to another name such as "accountname", it throws following exception
[UserDetailsService returned null...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3sUv.png)

I know the problem is related to 'getUsername()'. This getter is also a overide method of UserDetails interface.
Take into consideration, the getter becomes this:

```
@Override
public String getUsername() {
return getAccountname();
}
```

But still not working. Does it mean the name of the attribute cannot be altered?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. [Check out how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Try narrowing down the problem and only posting relevant code!

Comment: Have you also changed the loadUserByUsername method to use the accountName field?

Comment: @dunni Yes, loadUserByUsername is altered to loadUserByAccountname.